# Add values into hidden form fields using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-tag-manager, hidden-field

I am trying to insert a string into the form hidden field using JS and google tag manager.

This is the script/method (worked on a bunch of different forms)

```
(function(){

var selector1 = $('[id="label-utm_source-f7d353cc-c056-400e-a41a-2b022eaf4340_7665"]') 
$(selector1).val('{{Read UTM Medium cookie}}');

})();

</script>
```

or

```
var selector1 = $('input name="utm_original_lead_source"') 
$(selector1).val('{{Read cookie-UTM source}}');
```

And nothing worked. Any idea what I'm missing here ?

Thank you!

This is the form field:

[image]

Comment: Your second example is missing `[]` around the `name=xxx` selector.

Comment: Check the console for errors. That being said I would assume that GTM is dynamically adding/amending the elements *after* the page loads, so you most likely need to hook to one of the events it exposes before accessing the DOM

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan jQuery is generally silent when a selector doesn't match.

Comment: Use `#xxx` rather than `[id="xxx"]` to select by ID, although the latter should work correctly.

Comment: You don't need to put `selector1` inside `$()`. It's already a jQuery object.

Comment: Please post a [mre]. What you've written is pretty simple and should work. Are you sure `{{Read UTM Medium cookie}}` is getting the desired value? Look at the generated code to confirm that the right value has been substituted.

Answer (score 0):

A css selector is actually a string. So this cannot work:

```
var selector1 = $('[id="label-utm_source-f7d353cc-c056-400e-a41a-2b022eaf4340_7665"]') 
$(selector1).val('{{Read UTM Medium cookie}}');
```

it should be something like this:

```
var selector1 = '*[id="label-utm_source-f7d353cc-c056-400e-a41a-2b022eaf4340_7665"]';
$(selector1).val('{{Read UTM Medium cookie}}');
```

This is also wrong:

```
var selector1 = $('input name="utm_original_lead_source"') 
$(selector1).val('{{Read cookie-UTM source}}');
```

And should be like this:

```
var selector1 = 'input[name="utm_original_lead_source"]';
$(selector1).val('{{Read cookie-UTM source}}');
```

Comment: Thank you. Tested your approach, the script is executed (on click) with the right utm value but when I try to retrieve it in the console using document.querySelector('input[name=utm_original_lead_source]').value
 I get : ' '

Screenshot script execution [link](https://snipboard.io/qV9wnk.jpg)
Screenshot value retrieval in console : [link](https://snipboard.io/9TkNzA.jpg)

Comment: you are missing quotes for the attribute value: ‘input[name=“utm_original_lead_source”]'

Comment: still nothing using ‘input[name=“utm_original_lead_source”]

Comment: that selector should return all the input elements having the attribute name with a value = utm_original_lead_source. if none come out, there aren’t any. But how can I help you further if some information is missing?

Comment: is it possible that the field itself doesn't allow "write" ? Value to write into the field is there, the script is executed as expected but when I try to retrieve it I get nothing.

Comment: There’s no way that a css selector didn’t work to collect html elements. If it didn’t return elements I grant you there’s no element in that document matching the criteria of that selector. I’m sorry I’m out of clues to correctly address the problem you are having now